# Adaptar campos del formulario al tamaño de un div

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Un formulario y necesito hacer que se adapte al tamaño del `div` que lo contiene estoy usando Bootstrap 4, entiendo que es con flex de Bootstrap pero no me funciona, pues se salen los `input`s del formulario.

Éste es mi código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-12 d-flex" style="background-color:rgb(211, 194, 232); height: 270px;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="form-group col-8 p-2">
        <label for="accion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Accion:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion" size="1">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-8 p-0 m-0">
        <label for="Accion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Accion:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-8 p-0 m-0">
        <label for="Accion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Accion para:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Accion">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-8 p-0 m-0">
        <label for="Accion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Mto. Accion:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Accion">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-8 p-0 m-0">
        <label for="Accion" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Sub. respuesta:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="Accion">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                    </select>
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="Accion"></textarea>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <!-- Agregado -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se salen , se simula que están fuera por el background que le añadiste una altura `height: 270px;` y no es suficiente para  todos los elementos , si le quitas dicha propiedad funcionará correctamente

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex" style="background-color:rgb(211, 194, 232); height: 270px;">
```

Por

```
<div class="col-12 d-flex" style="background-color:rgb(211, 194, 232);">
```

Comment: Excelente tenias razón! Muchas gracias!